# How to make down arrow and enter key working in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have just started with writing scripts in AutoHotkey. I got the following working smoothly: I opened my program, performed Ctrl+I, then bottom option from dropdown menu. Here is my script:

```
Run, path\name_of_my_program.exe

; Wait for the name_of_my_program app window to become active (optional, but recommended)
WinWaitActive, ahk_exe name_of_my_program.exe, , 10 ; Wait for the app window to become active within 10 seconds (adjust the timeout as needed)

if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, name_of_my_program did not open successfully.


    }
else
{
    ; Simulate the shortcut Ctrl+I
    SendInput, ^i
    ; Wait for the "Choose File" window to appear
    ; WinWaitActive, Open
    ; Simulate pressing the Tab key (choose the Import option)
    SendInput, S ^{Tab}
    ; Simulate clicking on the "I" key
    SendInput, I
    ; Send Tab key six times
    SendInput, {Tab 6}
    ; Send Arrow Down key twice
    SendInput, {Down}
    ; Send Enter key once
    SendInput, {Enter}
    
}
```

My expectation: After this step

```
; Send Tab key six times
    SendInput, {Tab 6}
```

I would like to go down twice with Down keyboard and click on Enter key. Hence, I wrote this

```
    ; Send Arrow Down key twice
    SendInput, {Down}
    ; Send Enter key once
    SendInput, {Enter}
```

However, this part does not work. My questions are

1. How can I get this part working or how to debug it?
2. How can I change to Graph tab? ClassNN for thistab and other are TPageControl1. How can I make this choice?
3. More general version of 2. How to get a button working whose ClassNN is unique and I know the name of it?

Comment: Send Arrow Down key twice is `SendInput, {Down 2}`. To simulate pressing the Tab key try `SendInput, {Tab}`. If the ClassNN is visible in Window Spy if you move the mouse over that control, you can try [ControlClick](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlClick.htm). In any case, try your code step by step: If you see that the first command is working  add the second, save and reload the script and so on. See also [Debugging a Script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Scripts.htm#debug).

Comment: @user3419297 unfortunately, `SendInput` works until `{Down 2}` part. As of that line, it dos not work properly.

Comment: Does it work, if you manually press the Down key twice after `SendInput, {Tab 6}`? Which program is it and what are you trying to do in it?

Comment: yes, manually it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out! It turns out that I should add `KeyWait LWin` after else. Then, I added pause time so that the program takes its time to open screen to execute the command.

Here is the updated solution:

```
Run, path\name_of_my_program.exe

; Wait for the name_of_my_program app window to become active (optional, but recommended)
WinWaitActive, ahk_exe name_of_my_program.exe, , 10 ; Wait for the app window to become active within 10 seconds (adjust the timeout as needed)


if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, name_of_my_program did not open successfully.
}
else
{
    KeyWait LWin
    ; Simulate the shortcut Ctrl+I
    SendInput, ^i
    ; Wait for the "Choose File" window to appear
    ; WinWaitActive, Open
    ; Simulate pressing the Tab key (choose the Import option)
    SendInput, S ^{Tab}
    ; Simulate clicking on the "I" key
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, I
    ; Send Tab key six times
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Tab 6}
    ; ClipWait, 2
    ; Send Arrow Down key twice
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Down}
        ; Send Arrow Down key twice
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Down}
    ; Send Enter key once 
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Enter}
    ; Send Right key once 
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Right 4}
    ; Send Enter key once 
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Tab 3}
    ; Send Enter key twice 
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Enter 2}
    ; Send Left key once 
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Home}
    ; Simulate clicking on the "G" key
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, G_
    ; Send Enter key twice 
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Enter}
}
```